# Trying to process form but returning a object?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Why am I returning an object: null prototype. From the tutorials, I'm following using body parser to process a form it allows you to return your form in this format:{ Alert: 'This is an alert' }. But what I'm returning is :[Object: null prototype] { Alert: 'This is an alert' }.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})  

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log(request.body);
})
```

Index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" media="screen" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Alerts</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>By: a a</p>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    Enter your alert: <input type="text" name="Alert" id="Alert">
    <button type="submit">Submit Alert</button>
  </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: typo:  req.body?

Comment: Still no change in the output. Thanks for catching that though.

Comment: Can we see index.html?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: I'm not following what the issue is exactly, but the data _should_ be an object. That's how the body parser works. If you want a response on the webpage, however, then you will need to send a response in your Node.js code: `res.send(req.body.Alert);`

Comment: It seems to work.  What do you expect to be different?  I made a codesandbox for you:  https://codesandbox.io/s/4wx921onq7

Comment: Ok. Looks like I misunderstood how body parser works.@jakerella.

Comment: @JimB. I need to do some more reading on body parser thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }
```